# A single word that means "a group of people fascinated about something complex"

Tags: single-word-requests

Edit: Apologies for how little details I have recollection of.

So, a while ago I came across a very bizarre single word that someone used to describe "a group of people meeting to discuss complex matters that they don't necessarily fully understand, yet all the rest are fascinated, or mind blown by the apparent cleverness of the talker".
Now I can't seem to recall what it was neither find anything like that searching the internet. Can someone help recovering that word. I'd know the correct answer because then it would lead me to the same discussion on the internet that I lost the link to.

I vaguely remember that it might have had a `b` in it, it wasn't short but wasn't long either

Comment: Is it **obsessive**?

Comment: @Greybeard no that's a pretty common word, it was something very bizarre, a word that I never heard before. Also, it didn't mean obsessing over something, more like being fascinated at the apparent complexity or cleverness of it

Comment: Is the word explicitly referring to a group, or to an individual, or is it an adjective describing that behaviour?

Comment: 'Enthralled' comes close, I think, especially considering the idea that one is in a state of being a thrall, enslaved to a 'higher power'. Is it that?

Comment: @Joachim as far as memory serves it was used as an adjective, it just described that behavior, it was used to describe people attending those conferences and being fascinated/confused at the extra clever topics they were talking about

Comment: @Joachim unfortunately it was not enthralled either, it was a rare-er word

Comment: Hello, Ricky. We _do_ need an example sentence for a single-word-request. Your title seems to demand a noun, while 'used to describe' allows an adjective.

Comment: This is where I'd start your search [synonyms for *aficionado*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/aficionado).  Of course, M-W is just one of many potential resources. The idea is you're looking for the concept of some dedicated cohort of a person or topic. For example, I call myself an *acolyte* of the J programming language. That kinda thing (and the words *energumen* and *nympholept* were new and entertaining to me).

Comment: I can imaging *sybaritic* being used in those circumstances. *Adulatory* is maybe more on point.

Comment: _Enthused_ (_adj._) (_enthuse_ for the verb) (formed as a back-formation from _enthusiasm_) comes to mind, as it is usually used for a group of people filled with enthusiasm about something. Although, the question requires an example sentence to be able to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Buff** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buff#English)) A person who is very interested in a particular subject.

- If you are looking for a word meaning "the not knowledgeable buff", I can't think of a word that does not have a religious overtone. Some such words are "[fanatic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fanatic)", "[devotee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devotee#English)" and "[chela(Hindi Etymology)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chela)".

-Some words having the meaning of "beginner" are "**amateur**" and "**neophyte**"

**Amateur** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amateur#Noun))

1. A lover of something.
2. A person attached to a particular pursuit, study, science, or art (such as music or painting), especially one who cultivates any study, interest, taste, or attachment without engaging in it professionally.
3. Someone who is unqualified or insufficiently skillful.

**Neophyte** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neophyte#English))

1. A beginner; a person who is new to a subject, skill, or belief.
2. A novice (recent convert); a new convert or proselyte; a new monk.

Answer (score -1):

***Bemused*** describes a kind of thoughtful confusion where one may be fascinated by something they do not understand. This seems to cover some aspects of what you're after, as it indicates a lack of understanding and may imply a level of thoughtfulness or attention.